# Priniting graph label in GGPLOT2 when making a custom R function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, label

Hello fellow R Chads,

I am trying to make a custom function that prints a lorenz curve with `ggplot2` when given the name of a data frame. The function creates a graph, but I am having a hard time adding the name of the data frame to the title of the graph. This is what I have so far...

```
## func for Lorenz curve & GINI 

lorenz <- function(team){
  
  team <- team %>% arrange(PTS)
  team$Count = 1:nrow(team)
  team$PTSPERC <- ((team$PTS)/(sum(team$PTS)))
  
  team$CUMSUMPTS <- cumsum(team$PTSPERC)
  
  team <- team %>% 
    count(Count) %>% 
    mutate(Cum = cumsum(n)/sum(n)) %>% 
    select(-n) %>% 
    right_join(team) %>%
    select(names(team), everything())
  
  print(ggplot(team, aes(x = Cum, y = CUMSUMPTS))+
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)+
    geom_smooth() + 
    ylab("Quartiles of Points")+
    xlab("Quartiles")+
    theme_minimal()+
      labs(title = paste(print(team),"-  Lorenz Curve")))+
    annotate("text", x=.25, y=.82, label = paste("GINI coeff",signif(Gini(team$PTS),4)))
  
  Gini(team$PTS)
}

##

distplot(BUT)
lorenz(BUT)
```

[This is what it outputs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYm5B.png) I have tried to make a list of the name value, but I don't know how to call them into the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `deparse(substitute(team))` to get the name of the dataframe as a character string.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

foo <- function(team) {
  team_str <- deparse(substitute(team))

  ggplot(team, aes(hp, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = paste(team_str, "-  Lorenz Curve"))
}

foo(mtcars)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You! its so simple once you know what you don't know.